# decode response cmd to utf-8

Tags: utf-8, cmd, decode

The request in cmd:

```
curl -G -k https://api-ip.fssprus.ru/api/v1.0/result?" -d "@/test/request11.JSON" -o "/test/response11.JSON" -D "/test/hdrout2.HDR" -H "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

and get response

```
{"status":"success","code":0,"exception":"","response":{"status":0,"task_start":"2018-05-16 10:58:42","task_end":"2018-05-16 10:58:45","result":[{"status":0,"query":{"type":1,"params":{"region":"16","firstname":"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d","secondname":"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447","lastname":"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432","birthdate":"11.06.1975"}},"result":[]}]}}
```

How can I decode encoding so that the answer comes in the form of `utf-8` ?

Comment: JSON-parse the response. You want to do that on the command line…?

Comment: That's valid (though not necessary) escaping of strings in JSON. Use a proper JSON parser to read the response and it'll do the unescaping for you.

Comment: @deceze  I send a request to the site through the command line, the request is successfully suited. But the answer is returned in a different encoding. In this encoding Russian letters are encoded

Comment: @JoachimSauer what parser? sorry, but can you write example?

Comment: JSON is a specific data format. In JSON, characters *can* be encoded as `\u....`. To make those human-readable, you need to *parse the JSON* using a *JSON parser*. Typically you use JSON in the context of some programming language to automate something, and virtually all programming languages are capable of parsing JSON. So… in what context exactly are you using this? Just manually?

Comment: @deceze I have a macro code that at some point sends a request to the site through the command line. The response from the site is saved to a file and then it is disassembled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe this the output through [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It handles a lot of JSON management, including displaying UTF-8.

There are other tools like `json_pp`, which is part of most Perl distributions, which will also decode the UTF-8 for you.